# После закрытия окна PyQt5 музыка не перестает играть

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, closeevent

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent, QMediaPlaylist
from openpyxl import load_workbook



class Ui_cityquestion1(object):
def setupUi(self, cityquestion1):
        cityquestion1.setObjectName("cityquestion1")
        cityquestion1.resize(1223, 800)
        cityquestion1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.task = QtWidgets.QLabel(cityquestion1)
        self.task.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1231, 81))
        self.task.setStyleSheet("color: #000;\n"
"font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: rgb(214, 146, 255);")
        self.task.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.task.setObjectName("task")
        self.answer1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(cityquestion1)
        self.answer1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 520, 291, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.answer1.setFont(font)
        self.answer1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: rgb(112, 107, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #00FFFF;\n"
"border-radius: 10px\n"
"}\n")
        self.answer1.setObjectName("answer1")
        self.answer2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(cityquestion1)
        self.answer2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 520, 291, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.answer2.setFont(font)
        self.answer2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: rgb(112, 107, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #00FFFF;\n"
"border-radius: 10px\n"
"}\n")
        self.answer2.setObjectName("answer2")
        self.answer3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(cityquestion1)
        self.answer3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 650, 291, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.answer3.setFont(font)
        self.answer3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: rgb(112, 107, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #00FFFF;\n"
"border-radius: 10px\n"
"}\n")
        self.answer3.setObjectName("answer3")
        self.answer4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(cityquestion1)
        self.answer4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 650, 291, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.answer4.setFont(font)
        self.answer4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: rgb(112, 107, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #00FFFF;\n"
"border-radius: 10px\n"
"}\n")
        self.answer4.setObjectName("answer4")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(cityquestion1)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 100, 741, 381))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("questionsimages/city/cityquestion1.jpg"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(cityquestion1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(cityquestion1)

def retranslateUi(self, cityquestion1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        cityquestion1.setWindowTitle(_translate("cityquestion1", "CityQuestion_1"))
        self.task.setText(_translate("cityquestion1", "Toto mesto, hlavné mesto ktorej krajiny ?"))
        self.answer1.setText(_translate("cityquestion1", "Rusko"))
        self.answer2.setText(_translate("cityquestion1", "Bielorusko"))
        self.answer3.setText(_translate("cityquestion1", "Francúzsko"))
        self.answer4.setText(_translate("cityquestion1", "Fínsko"))

class MainWindow1(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_cityquestion1):
def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 

        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
        self.url = QUrl.fromLocalFile("audio/clock.mp3")
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(self.url))
        self.playlist.setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist.Loop)
        self.clock = QMediaPlayer()
        self.clock.setPlaylist(self.playlist)
        self.clock.setVolume(20)
        self.clock.play()

if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icons/city.svg'))
wd = MainWindow1()
wd.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Этот код я вызываю из другого окна вот так:

```
 self.window = MainWindow1()
 self.window.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QWidget::[**closeEvent**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#closeEvent)(QCloseEvent *event)
>
> Этот обработчик событий вызывается с данным event, когда Qt получает от оконной системы запрос на закрытие окна для виджета верхнего уровня.
>
> Вы можете переопределить эту функцию, чтобы изменить способ, которым виджет отвечает на запросы закрытия окна.

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent, QMediaPlaylist
# ???from openpyxl import load_workbook


class Ui_cityquestion1(object):
    def setupUi(self, cityquestion1):
            cityquestion1.setObjectName("cityquestion1")
            cityquestion1.resize(1223, 800)
            cityquestion1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
            self.task = QtWidgets.QLabel(cityquestion1)
            self.task.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1231, 81))
            self.task.setStyleSheet("color: #000;\n"
    "font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: rgb(214, 146, 255);")
            self.task.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.task.setObjectName("task")
            self.answer1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(cityquestion1)
            self.answer1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 520, 291, 81))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
            font.setPointSize(24)
            font.setBold(False)
            font.setItalic(False)
            font.setWeight(50)
            self.answer1.setFont(font)
            self.answer1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
    "font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: rgb(112, 107, 255);\n"
    "border-radius: 10px\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:hover{\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
    "font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #00FFFF;\n"
    "border-radius: 10px\n"
    "}\n")
            self.answer1.setObjectName("answer1")
            self.answer2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(cityquestion1)
            self.answer2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 520, 291, 81))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
            font.setPointSize(24)
            font.setBold(False)
            font.setItalic(False)
            font.setWeight(50)
            self.answer2.setFont(font)
            self.answer2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
    "font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: rgb(112, 107, 255);\n"
    "border-radius: 10px\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:hover{\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
    "font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #00FFFF;\n"
    "border-radius: 10px\n"
    "}\n")
            self.answer2.setObjectName("answer2")
            self.answer3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(cityquestion1)
            self.answer3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 650, 291, 81))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
            font.setPointSize(24)
            font.setBold(False)
            font.setItalic(False)
            font.setWeight(50)
            self.answer3.setFont(font)
            self.answer3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
    "font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: rgb(112, 107, 255);\n"
    "border-radius: 10px\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:hover{\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
    "font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #00FFFF;\n"
    "border-radius: 10px\n"
    "}\n")
            self.answer3.setObjectName("answer3")
            self.answer4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(cityquestion1)
            self.answer4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 650, 291, 81))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
            font.setPointSize(24)
            font.setBold(False)
            font.setItalic(False)
            font.setWeight(50)
            self.answer4.setFont(font)
            self.answer4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
    "font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: rgb(112, 107, 255);\n"
    "border-radius: 10px\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:hover{\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
    "font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
    "border: none;\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #00FFFF;\n"
    "border-radius: 10px\n"
    "}\n")
            self.answer4.setObjectName("answer4")
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(cityquestion1)
            self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 100, 741, 381))
            self.label.setText("")
            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("questionsimages/city/cityquestion1.jpg"))
            self.label.setObjectName("label")

            self.retranslateUi(cityquestion1)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(cityquestion1)

    def retranslateUi(self, cityquestion1):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            cityquestion1.setWindowTitle(_translate("cityquestion1", "CityQuestion_1"))
            self.task.setText(_translate("cityquestion1", "Toto mesto, hlavné mesto ktorej krajiny ?"))
            self.answer1.setText(_translate("cityquestion1", "Rusko"))
            self.answer2.setText(_translate("cityquestion1", "Bielorusko"))
            self.answer3.setText(_translate("cityquestion1", "Francúzsko"))
            self.answer4.setText(_translate("cityquestion1", "Fínsko"))


class MainWindow1(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_cityquestion1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 

        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
        self.url = QUrl.fromLocalFile("sounds/zvuki_prirody.mp3")
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(self.url))
        self.playlist.setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist.Loop)
        self.clock = QMediaPlayer()
        self.clock.setPlaylist(self.playlist)
        self.clock.setVolume(20)
        self.clock.play()
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):                                      # +++
        self.clock.stop()                                             # +++
        event.accept()                                                # +++
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()   

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Открыть окно MainWindow1')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.open_window1)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def open_window1(self):
        self.window1 = MainWindow1()
        self.window1.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('im.png'))
# !!!
    wd = MainWindow()                                        # MainWindow1()
    
    wd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо ВАМ большое !

Comment: ♥️♥️♥️. Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @Lama пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour  !!!

Comment: Да я уже работаю над этим вопросом )